# Modin Pandas and Dask Does nothing but hang

Tags: python, pandas, modin

I am trying to decipher why this is just hanging with modin and works fine with regular pandas:

```
import modin.pandas as pd

infile1 = 'D:\\test_files\\curves_crosstab.csv'
infile2 = 'D:\\test_files\\8760_crosstab.csv'
infilenames = [infile1, infile2]

outfile1 = 'D:\\test_files\\curves_sample_output.csv'
outfile2 = 'D:\\test_files\\8760_sample_output.csv'

for i in range(len(infilenames)) :
    if 'curves' in infilenames[i] :
        print("in curves")
        df = pd.read_csv(infilenames[i], header=[0,1,2,3])
        print("read curves")
        df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
        print("indexed columns")
        df.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df.columns]
        print("joined columns")
        df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['Unnamed: 0_level_0_Unnamed: 0_level_1_Unnamed: 0_level_2_Year',
            'Unnamed: 1_level_0_Unnamed: 1_level_1_Unnamed: 1_level_2_Month',
            'Unnamed: 2_level_0_Unnamed: 2_level_1_Unnamed: 2_level_2_Day',
            'Unnamed: 3_level_0_Unnamed: 3_level_1_Unnamed: 3_level_2_Hour'])
        print("melted")
        df2 = pd.concat([df2,df2.variable.str.split('_',expand=True)],axis=1)
        del df2['variable']
        print("deleted variable column")
        df2.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0_level_0_Unnamed: 0_level_1_Unnamed: 0_level_2_Year' : 'Year' ,
                            'Unnamed: 1_level_0_Unnamed: 1_level_1_Unnamed: 1_level_2_Month' : 'Month',
                            'Unnamed: 2_level_0_Unnamed: 2_level_1_Unnamed: 2_level_2_Day' : 'Day',
                            'Unnamed: 3_level_0_Unnamed: 3_level_1_Unnamed: 3_level_2_Hour' : 'Hour',
                            0 : 'currency', 
                            1 : 'consultant_or_case', 
                            2 : 'name', 
                            3 : 'hub', 
                            'value' : 'rate_in_local_currency'}, inplace = True)
        print("renamed")
        pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df2, path_or_buf=outfile1,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
        print("created csv")
    else :

        df = pd.read_csv(infilenames[i], encoding='cp1252')
        df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['Month','Day','Hour'])

        pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df2, path_or_buf=outfile2,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

when I ran this under pandas it executed, but took an average of 87 seconds due to the size of the curves files (~36.5MB in and ~395MB out), I was hoping modin could cut that time.  The script when swapped to Modin runs, but it just sits and doesn't do anything.  It doesn't even give me

> ```
> Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:14618 to respond...
> Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:31410 to respond...
> Starting local scheduler with the following resources: {'CPU': 4, 'GPU': 0}.
> ```

I don't know if that should show up in the console or not, but it doesn't.  the script gets to the first reading of the csv, as I get in curves.  Then it just sits.  Never doing anything else.  How can I figure out what is going on?

OS is Windows10 if that matters.